# MySQL Connection not available in Flask python

Tags: python, mysql, api, flask, mysql-connector

I am new to flask.
Flask server give MY SQL Connection not available whenever I call two many API request at a  same time and my server get crash
I do not know my its happening. I also increase **connect_timeout** to 600 but it still gives the same error.
MySQL timeout Variables are:
[SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%timeout"; SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S6p3.png)

This only happened when i call many API request at a same time

Error:
[Error given my Flask server SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz80n.png)

My API code.
This API running a Imageproccesing Modal at **visualizer.image_processing**
and enter detect faces id into MYSQL database

```
@attendance.route('/groups/mark_attendence', methods=['POST', 'GET'],)
def mark_attendence():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    image_b64 = request.get_json()['im']
    group_id = request.get_json()['gid']
    foldername = request.get_json()['folder_name']
    session_id = request.get_json()['sessionid']
    data = urllib.parse.unquote(image_b64)
    data = data.split(',')[1]
    imgdata = base64.b64decode(data)
    filename ="imageToSave" + str(group_id) + ".jpg"
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f: 
        f.write(imgdata)
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    args = Args(folderName=foldername)
    visualizer = Visualizer(args)
    array_findFaces = visualizer.image_processing(img)
    cursor1 = mysql.cursor()
    try:
        if len(array_findFaces) > 0:
                for i in array_findFaces:
                    if(i['text'] != 'Unknown'):
                        cursor1.execute(
                            "UPDATE  usersdb.sessions  SET status = 1 WHERE status = 0 and  sessionid = '"+ str(session_id) +"' and uid = '"+ str(student[1]) +"' ; ")
        else: 
            print("----------------No face detected----------------")
    except Exception as e :
        print("exception in mark attendance")
        print(e)
    mysql.commit()
    cursor1.close()
    cursor2 = mysql.cursor()
    cursor2.execute("select name, pic,status,usersdb.sessions.updated_at,uid,email from usersdb.user join usersdb.sessions on usersdb.user.id = usersdb.sessions.uid  where  usersdb.sessions.sessionid = '" + str(session_id) + "'")
    data = cursor2.fetchall()  
    cursor2.close()
    then = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("time taken to mark attendence")
    print(then - now)
    finaljson = json.dumps({'Faces': array_findFaces,"Attendance":"nothing"},indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
    return finaljson
```

I connect my Flask server to MYSQL using a package called my **mysql.connector**

```
import mysql.connector
    
try:
   mysql = mysql.connector.connect(
   host="localhost",
   user="root",
   passwd="******",
   database="usersdb")
except:
   print("Error connecting to database")
```

and imported my mysql connection like that

```
import json
from config.db_connect import mysql // imported mysql connection
from sqlite3 import Date
import jsonpickle
from json import JSONEncoder
import flask
import os
import datetime
import numpy as np
from flask import Blueprint,request
from face_2 import Visualizer
import io
import cv2, os, base64, uuid, shutil
import urllib.parse
from PIL import Image
```

At the Sametime i also call another API parallel to first API

```
@attendance.route('/groups/markbyuid', methods=['POST'])
def mark_by_uid():
    uid = request.get_json()['uid']
    status = request.get_json()['status']
    sessionId = request.get_json()['sessionId']
    try:
     
        cursor = mysql.cursor()
        cursor.execute(" update usersdb.sessions set status = '" +str( status) + "' where uid = '" + str(uid) + "' and sessionid = '" + str(sessionId) + "' ")
        mysql.commit()
        cursor.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print('exception is here ')
        print(e)
    return flask.jsonify({'data': 'success'})
```

So both two api called at a same time

Moreover sometime give **MySQL Connection not available. Segmentation Fault.** [Segmentation Fault Error SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd1P1.png) and my server stopped

Why my server stopped and gives error when two API's called at same Time? I checked my API's routes many time it looks fine. Reminder both API's Update the same database table

Comment: What, exactly, is `mysql` in the code?  Can you [edit] the question to share how it is set up?

Comment: i have shared my sql connection code

Comment: It looks like you are using a single connection - you need to use a pool, as described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connection-pooling.html), to service concurrent requests.

Comment: i used that pool but it still give the same error

Comment: i edit the question kindly read it again

Comment: I am also facing this issue using multiple API call . Between API call my SQL connection gone away. I am calling multiple API around 1-200 at the same time , API count is not fixed. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by using an other package `flaskext.mysql`

```py
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = '123456'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'facerecognition'


from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
mysql = MySQL()
cursor = mysql.get_db().cursor()
cursor.execute("Your sql query")
mysql.get_db().commit()
```

this package solves this connection loss problem. It worked in my case. Hope it will work in your problem. Read more about this package [flask-mysql](https://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)